# Is it possible in google app engine (go) to format a date using the users local web browser timezone?

Tags: google-app-engine, go

Is it possible in google app engine (go) to format a date using the users local web browser timezone?

Ultimately users should be able to pick/adjust their timezone, but for now the users computer timezone should be sufficient.

Comment: Sorry for such fragmentary help, but I've approached it (not in Go/App Engine, but in Web apps) by having the server a UTC timestamp that JavaScript can understand; when JS parses a date, it will implicitly convert it to the user's system timezone. Haven't looked at the legacy-browser compat of this, but `d=new Date(Date.parse("2014-01-01T01:01:01-0000")); console.log(d.getHours())` will log a timezone-dependent hour in at least one modern browser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would need to send that information along the http request and then make sure is one of appengine's recognized timezones and then format it with the time package

you can read more about the whole thing here:

http://www.goinggo.net/2013/08/using-time-timezones-and-location-in-go.html

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your application, but an appengine http request header should include few variables, namely 'X-AppEngine-Country' which is the country from which the request originated, as an ISO 3166-1 alpha-2 country code, determined from the client's IP address.

You may then able to use this country code (i.e. AU, GB) to detect the sender timezone and format the UTC time to local.

http://golang.org/pkg/time/

For user selected timezone, you would need to pass an information in as you may know.

Comment: You are also likely to get an Accept-Language header, which will give you further information on the user's expectations.