# Why is Google App Engine parsing different time?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-app-engine

My application heavily relies on time calculation and I read online that GCP App Engine uses UTC time zone.
So I made these calculations and on my local dev, the calcTime is totally different than App Engine, App Engine is giving me a big -negative number I'm not sure why??

```
    const endTime = Math.floor(new Date(filteredTimeLeft).getTime() / 1000);
const convertSec = Number(coin.seconds);
const dateNow = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);
const calcTime = endTime - convertSec - dateNow;
```

Isn't my code suppose to work universally , independent where the server is located at?

Comment: What is the format of *filteredTimeLeft*? What result are you expecting? What did you get? Perhaps see [*Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results)

Comment: Format of filteredTimeLeft is Sun, Feb 06, 2022 05:35:36 PM

Comment: The value of calcTime is different from my local dev and the cloud app engine? why is that?

Comment: Your local dev is NOT an exact replica of App Engine. You have to run your code on production to see if it's using UTC or not. A better option is for your code to explicitly call UTC

Comment: thats what i did here     const endTime = moment(filteredTimeLeft, "ddd MMM DD YYYY hh:mm:ss a").utcOffset("-08:00").unix();
    const convertSec = Number(coin.seconds);
    const dateNow = moment().utcOffset("-08:00").unix();;

Comment: Extra information should be added to the OP, not just in comments. Moment.js parse tokens "ddd MMM DD YYYY hh:mm:ss a" don't match the input string (commas are missing). If parsed correctly, it will be parsed as local (or perhaps an invalid date), so represents a different moment in time for each host with a different offset. Applying an offset afterward is too late, it's already been parsed. It doesn't change the time value generated from the string, only output values.

Comment: As proof, `moment().utcOffset("-08:00").unix() === moment().unix()` with about 99.999% certainty (there's a minuscule chance that the system clock ticks between calls to *moment* and results in 1 second discrepancy).

Comment: ok? how does this help this question tho

Comment: You may have a look at this [Stackoverflow case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24748597/is-it-possible-in-google-app-engine-go-to-format-a-date-using-the-users-local). Let me know if that helps!